# Не работает код вставки изображения на fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, fabricjs

Имеется код из офф документации fabric.js. 
Со вставкой изображения. 
Но он не работает. Вместо этого у меня пустая страница. 
Все пути проверил. Все верно. Консоль пустая.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>curveExample</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
<script src="fabric/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<img src="long-arrow-down.png" id="my-image" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-image');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
left: 100,
top: 100,
angle: 100,
opacity: 0.85
});
canvas.add(imgInstance);
</script>


<!--<script src="teat.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Русскоязычное руководство похоже устарело,смотрите лучше примеры в Demo на сайте.Скрипты подключать лучше перед закрывающим тегом BODY. 
Вот пример вставки картинки:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>curveExample</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
     (function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {
    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 }).scale(1));
   });
   })()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```